# While binding a custom component method to the component using BIND(), Can we pass in the first argument as the component itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I am trying to bind a custom component method to the component using "bind" because inside a custom component method "this" is actually null. I apologize if this sounds silly, but can't we pass in the first argument to the bind method as the component itself rather than passing the first argument as "this"? Because this refers to the component itself anyway.

````
        function FriendsList(props){
            return(
            <ul>
                {props.list.map((name)=>(
                    <li key={name}>
                        <span>{name}</span>
                        <button onClick= 
                         {()=>props.onRemoveFriend(name)}>Remove</button>
                    </li>
                    ))}
            </ul> 
            )


        }
        class App extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props)

                this.state={
                    friends:['Batman','Thor','Hulk']
                }
                **this.handleRemoveFriend=this.handleRemoveFriend.bind(this)**
            }
            handleAddFriend(){

            }
            handleRemoveFriend(name){
                  this.setState((currentState)=>{
                    return{

                friends:currentState.friends.filter((friend)=>friend!==name)
                    }
                  })
            }
            render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <FriendsList 
                        list={this.state.friends}
                        onRemoveFriend={this.handleRemoveFriend}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            }

        }

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))


    </script>```

instead of "this.handleRemoveFriend=this.handleRemoveFriend.bind(this)". Can't we write "this.handleRemoveFriend=this.handleRemoveFriend.bind(App)"?
It gives me an error when I do so, saying this.setstate is not a function.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. `this` is the instance of your class, `App` is the class itself.